# Chat context menu no longer shows up

Tags: bug, sidebar

I used to get a chat context menu on the right side of the page. It said The Bridge (X people chatting). Underneath Minecraft or some such room (Y people chatting).

All I see now is the Network Hot Questions list instead.

Is this normal? I'd rather see our chat link. Maybe below our chat link they could do the hot questions.

Here is what it looks like. Please forgive me for the bad free style arrow. And my name is still Vaishali just written in Japanese as Vaish-ur-ari.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't appear there every time you load the page, same as the community ads

Comment: Blogs appear in the community bulletin with the popular meta discussions. It would be nice to get the Arqade blog going though.

Comment: Titanfall is out already..